# In NetSuite Saved Search, how to eliminate a record fully from result if any of the lines is matching the criteria

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to create a saved search which will show me list of Inbound Shipments where there is no 'ABC' Landed Cost Category.

I am using " Landed Cost Category None of 'ABC' " but in the result I am getting all the records, only the lines with 'ABC' category is not showing.

What I am expecting is if INBOUNDSHIPEMNT123 has 1 line with 'ABC' category and other lines with different categories, my search will complete eliminate INBOUNDSHIPEMNT123 as there is 1 'ABC' line. Currently only the ABC line is getting removed but the record is showing in the search result

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have Inbound Shipments enabled in my account, but I can show you a way to do this with any transaction type with grouping and summary criteria using formulas.

In my example, I’ll show you how to find any Sales Order that does NOT have a ‘Partner Discount’ item on it.

We’ll start a new Transaction saved search with the following criteria:

- Type = ‘Sales Order’
- Main Line = ‘No’
- Date Created on or after ‘1/1/2023’ (just to make the data set smaller)

On the results tab, we’ll add a formula field.  This isn’t required, but it helps us test the formula that we’ll need.  On the results tab:

- Document Number - GROUP
- Formula (Numeric) - SUM: `case when {item} = ‘Partner Discount’ then 1 else 0 end`

This formula will result in 0 for every line that isn’t a Partner Discount and 1 for every line that is a Partner Discount.  When we GROUP by Document Number and SUM by this formula, any transaction that has a 0 here does NOT have a Partner Discount.

Now, back in the Criteria section, on the Summary sub-tab, add this:

- SUM - Formula (Numeric) - is 0 - `case when {item} = ‘Partner Discount’ then 1 else 0 end`

This says that we only want to return rows (grouped by document number) where the sum of our formula is 0, meaning it doesn’t have any Partner Discount items.